# How to achieve a style that suits my type in WinUI?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, winui-3, winui

I have written seven style for a control in WinUI.I have a property called Type. It's a Enum.

If I specify a type for the MainWindow.xaml type property then the style should be published to that type.

But I have mentioned the same class as the TargetType of all the Style that I have written.

How to try to achieve the style of the type mentioned in my MainWindow.Xaml.

Example :

```
<Style x:Key="ShimmerFeedStyle" TargetType="local:Shimmer">
<Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{ThemeResource ShimmerFillColor}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:Shimmer">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Grid x:Name="Grid1">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Ellipse Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="0"  Height="100" Width="100"  Fill="{TemplateBinding Fill}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                            <Rectangle x:Name="rect1" Margin="120,0,0,40" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Height="30" Width="500"  Fill="{TemplateBinding Fill}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            </Rectangle>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="rect2" Margin="120,50,0,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Height="30" Width="300" Fill="{TemplateBinding Fill}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            </Rectangle>
                            <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Fill="{TemplateBinding Fill}" Margin="0,30,0,0" Height="200"  Width="625" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                            <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Fill="{TemplateBinding Fill}" Margin="0,20,0,0" Height="20" Width="625" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                            <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Fill="{TemplateBinding Fill}" Margin="0,20,0,0" Height="20" Width="625" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid x:Name="Grid2">
                            <ContentControl>
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                            </ContentControl>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
</Style>
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource ShimmerFeedStyle}" TargetType="local:Shimmer"/>
```

```
<Style x:Key="ShimmerVideoStyle" TargetType="local:Shimmer">
 <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{ThemeResource ShimmerFillColor}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:Shimmer">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Grid x:Name="Grid1">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Fill="{TemplateBinding Fill}" Margin="0,20,0,0" Height="250" Width="625" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                            <Ellipse Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Height="100" Width="100" Margin="0,40,0,0"  Fill="{TemplateBinding Fill}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                            <Rectangle Margin="130,30,0,30" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Height="28" Width="400"  Fill="{TemplateBinding Fill}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            </Rectangle>
                            <Rectangle Margin="130,80,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  Height="28" Width="400" Fill="{TemplateBinding Fill}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            </Rectangle>
                        </Grid>
                         <Grid x:Name="Grid2">
                                <ContentControl>
                                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                                </ContentControl>
                         </Grid>                     
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource ShimmerVideoStyle}" TargetType="local:Shimmer"/>
```

```
<Style x:Key="ShimmerProfileStyle" TargetType="local:Shimmer">
<Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{ThemeResource ShimmerFillColor}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:Shimmer">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Grid x:Name="Grid1">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Ellipse Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Height="100" Width="100" Fill="{TemplateBinding Fill}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                     VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Height="30" Width="150" Margin="0,45,0,0" Fill="{TemplateBinding Fill}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Height="30" Width="300" Margin="0,15,0,0" Fill="{TemplateBinding Fill}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Height="25" Width="500" Margin="0,40,0,0" Fill="{TemplateBinding Fill}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <Rectangle Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Height="25" Width="500" Margin="0,20,0,0" Fill="{TemplateBinding Fill}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid x:Name="Grid2">
                            <ContentControl>
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                            </ContentControl>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource ShimmerProfileStyle}" TargetType="local:Shimmer"/>
```

In all of those mentioned above for the example, the targettype represents the same class.

How to try to achieve the style of the type mentioned in my MainWindow.Xaml.

In MainWindow.Xaml:

```
<shim:Shimmer x:Name="shimmer" IsActive="True" Type="Feed">
            <shim:Shimmer.Content>
                <Grid>
                    <Image Height="100" Width="100" Source="D:\WinUI-3 Shimmer control\Syncfusion.Shimmer.WinUI\Shimmer\download.jfif"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Content is Loaded!" />
                </Grid>
            </shim:Shimmer.Content>
        </shim:Shimmer>
```

In my Shimmer Class:

```
public class Shimmer:Control
{
    public Shimmer()                                   
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey= typeof(Shimmer);
    }

 public ShimmerType Type
            {
                get { return (ShimmerType)GetValue(TypeProperty); }
                set { SetValue(TypeProperty, value); }
            }
            // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Type.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
            public static readonly DependencyProperty TypeProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register("Type", typeof(ShimmerType), typeof(SfShimmer), new PropertyMetadata(null,OnTypePropertyChanged)); }
```

Are there any solutions?

Comment: Do you want to apply a ``Style`` to Shimmer? For example, in your sample code, Type is "Profile", so you want to apply the "ShimmerProfileStyle"?

Comment: I am getting the error because I have given the same target type for all my styles.                                                                           
        That style should not be specified in the mainWindow.xaml page in WinUI. Is it possible to change the type-specific style with the TypeChangedProperty method?                               
        I will only specify its type in my mainwindow.xaml page. Please give instructions to automatically pick up the appropriate style in the codes.

Comment: Your ``Style``s has different ``key``s so usually that shouldn't be a problem. Where exactly are you getting this error? And what does it say?

Comment: The error I get  : Dictionary Item "Style" has duplicate  key "WinUI.Shimmer".

Comment: It seems that you're using the ``Shimmer`` feature from the **CommunityToolkit.Labs** and facing some kind of conflict. Can you share more code around your ``local:Shimmer``?, what's inside the ``Style``s and the ``MainWindow``?

Comment: In my question, I have shared three of my styles as examples and my class type property only. Please check that above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you shared more code we can see that you have 3 [implicit styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/styles/xaml?view=net-maui-7.0#:%7E:text=Each%20Style%20object%20can%20be%20explicit%2C%20or%20implicit%3A) targeting `local:Shimmer`.

Removing these `Style`s:

```xml
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource ShimmerFeedStyle}" TargetType="local:SfShimmer"/>
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource ShimmerVideoStyle}" TargetType="local:SfShimmer"/>
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource ShimmerProfileStyle}" TargetType="local:SfShimmer"/>
```

or setting the `x:Key` for each `Style` like this should make the error gone.

```xml
<Style x:Key="DefaultShimmerFeedStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource ShimmerFeedStyle}" TargetType="local:SfShimmer"/>
<Style x:Key="DefaultShimmerVideoStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource ShimmerVideoStyle}" TargetType="local:SfShimmer"/>
<Style x:Key="DefaultShimmerProfileStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource ShimmerProfileStyle}" TargetType="local:SfShimmer"/>
```

And usually, you don't apply a `Style` from inside, like I guess you are trying to do with the `Type` property. You just apply a `Style` like this:

```xml
<local:Shimmer Style="{StaticResource DefaultShimmerFeedStyle" />
```

Comment: Sir, Now this error are cleared. But how to get the appropriate style for a given shimmer Type property. How to implement it.

Comment: Updated my answer. I hope it helps.